# Use decision tree to learn precise classification rules: need accuracy of 1

Tags: r, cart, caret, rpart

I'm trying to use a decision tree algorithm to learn how general ledger transactions (10 digit code) are classified into *revenue, expense, G&A* et cetera without actually scripting every combination. There are general rules in our accounting software, and each digit of the 10-digit code has a specific meaning.

There are about ~6000 used combinations of these 10 digits, but only 6 to 9 categories that I want to classify them into. The rules are precise and there is no ambiguity, there are no outliers (e.g. if the 1st digit = 3, then it is revenue; if 2nd digit = 4 and 4th digit = 8 then it is cost of sale. And so on). By knowing which digits to check, one can write a compact `if else` set of statements.

I am using an `rpart` decision tree in `R` to get the rules, which I'm planning to then put into a `CASE WHEN` SQL statement.

*My problem is that the `rpart` algorithm is good, but it is not 100% precise. It drops a few smaller sized categories, and misses a few times.*

---

**How do I adjust the arguments of `rpart` (or use a different function and/or a different package, e.g. `caret`) to get a decision tree with an accuracy of 1?**

Thank you!

Comment: So basically you are asking how to force decision tree to overfit?

Comment: It seems that you found out how to disable the pruning in your decision tree function. You still need to be careful that your training set contains all possible combinations if you want to be sure to have accuracy 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but does setting the `cp` parameter in `rpart` to a negative value (let's say, -1) work? Also try setting the `minsplit` parameter to 2.

- The complexity parameter (with default value of 0.01) is there to prune the tree of nodes that would not decrease overall lack of fit by a factor of `cp`. By setting it to -1 you're telling it that you want it to be as precise as possible. In your case overfitting is actually desirable.
- `Minsplit` (with default value of 20) is the lowest amount of observations in a node at which split is attempted.

Let us know if it solved the problem completely or is there something more to it.

Comment: It worked! I think... I will validate tomorrow, but my tree just expanded!

Comment: I definitely got what I needed. I wasn't aware of the cf argument, and setting it to -1 solved the issue, as I wanted to overfit.

Now my task to to gather all of these branches into a concise `CASE WHEN` statement

Comment: @Taraas chechout the rpart.utils package that should do just what you want.

Comment: @gung :This was my first answer on the site and I tried to cut to the chase as fast as possible, because the question was rather simple. I understand that even now after the edit, the answer does not provide as much information as other beautiful answers i have seen from many users of stackexchange. Next time I'll try to explain it better right away.

Comment: Don't take it too hard, @ExabytE. I appreciate your efforts here. Thanks again.